# Calculate the Frequency of a term and Create stacked column graphic

Tags: r, plot, frequency

I'd like to calculate the frequency of each country code by year and make a stacked column graph "frequency x year", with the country codes being the stacked columns.

I'm beginner on R, and I don't know the best way to do this

Thanks.

```r
dput(head(table_suinos_p.country, 20))
structure(list(suinos.p.year = structure(c(9L, 8L, 14L, 7L, 14L, 
14L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 16L, 13L, 16L, 5L, 15L, 16L, 
9L, 18L), .Label = c("1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", 
"2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), 
    suinos.p.country = structure(c(4L, 17L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 17L, 
    11L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 11L, 
    6L, 11L), .Label = c("AU", "CA", "CN", "CU", "DE", "EP", 
    "FR", "GB", "IT", "JP", "KR", "PL", "RU", "SG", "TH", "TW", 
    "US", "WO"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide more details and what problems you are experiencing. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1) about making a reprex.

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.) And don't [cross post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401091/contar-numero-de-celulas-com-mesmo-valor-r).

Comment: thanks for the feedback and help. I'm new here

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic stacked bar chart with your example data.

```r
df %>% count(suinos.p.year,suinos.p.country) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(suinos.p.year,n,fill=suinos.p.country)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]